# Не работает css

Tags: css

```css
  * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f6f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.margin160 {
  margin: 10px 160px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #313030;
  height: 90px;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 360px;
}

.menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #d7d7d7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.float-left {
  width: 600px;
  float: left;
}

.float-left h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
}

.float-left p {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.float-left a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 60px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ff3333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  video {
    float: right;
  }
  .part2 {
    clear: both;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
  .part2 h1 {
    width: 100px;
  }
  table {
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="margin160">
      <div class="menu">

        <ul>

          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="float-left">
        <h1>Our strong organisation</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed sapien turpis. Duis finibus, purus vehicula efficitur imperdiet, turpis tellus rhoncus dui, finibus rutrum purus elit at leo. Nunc elit lacus, mollis sit amet suscipit sed, egestas
          nec metus. Praesent sit amet ultricies eros. Cras erat ipsum, cursus id lectus quis, accumsan placerat turpis. Donec luctus mattis quam quis sagittis. Nam ut lectus mauris. Curabitur porttitor congue metus vitae fringilla. Maecenas sapien arcu,
          venenatis eget libero ac, finibus dapibus quam.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Contact us</a>
      </div>
      <video width="400" height="300" controls="controls">
     <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
    </video>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="margin160">
    <div class="part2">
      <h1>Do you know We can provide for you?</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed sapien turpis. Duis finibus, purus vehicula efficitur imperdiet, turpis tellus rhoncus dui, finibus rutrum purus elit at leo. Nunc elit lacus, mollis sit amet suscipit sed, egestas
        nec metus. Praesent sit amet ultricies eros. Cras erat ipsum, cursus id lectus quis, accumsan placerat turpis. Donec luctus mattis quam quis sagittis. Nam ut lectus mauris. Curabitur porttitor congue met
      </p>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h2>Management</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h2>UI/UX Design</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed sapien turpis.</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed sapien turpis.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h2>Logo/Branding</h2>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h2>Animation</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed sapien turpis.</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sed sapien turpis.</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Почему при выборе .part2 не работают на него никакие селекторы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыли скобку закрыть в `css` перед строкой `video {`

Comment: спасибо не заметил